# Close the current and the previous activity when button get clicked

Tags: android

Let say there 3 activities :

```
Activity A  
Activity B  
Activity C
```

Then on Activity C, there is a button FinishButton
So, the behavior that I want on Activity C is that :
1. If I press back button , the Activity C will get closed then we will see the Activity B (just like normal behavior)
2. If I press FinishButton , the Activity B and Activity C will get closed then we will see the Activity A

Is there a way to do this ?
I do some research but only to find a way to close all previous activities.

Comment: By "close" you mean "change"?

Comment: no change , just simply close the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `startActivityForResult`and `setResult()`.

When you start Activity C, start it using `startActivityForResult` and in Activity C set the result to `RESULT_CANCELED`. Check this flag in Activity B. If its OK, then don't do anything, but if its `RESULT_CANCELED` then just finish Activity B.

you can implement it as follows:

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        //initialize btn;
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class),100); 
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 100){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //Do nothing
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
    }
    }
}
```

**ActivityC.java**

```
public class ActivityC extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button btnFinish;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        //initialize btnFinish;
         btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
               finish();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I never use those , can you give me the code example ?

Comment: @phaphapha I have already provided the code examples. Is it not clear?

Comment: @phaphapha no problem. Enjoy Coding :-)

Comment: Is it okay if i switch the RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED ?  Because if I click back button, that should mean cancelled , right?

Comment: Never mind, I use the exact code you post, and the behavior is not right.  If I click Back Button, it would go back to Activity B. But if I click Finish Button, it will also go back to Activity B. I even tried to use Toast on that if resultCode , but have no response at all. So, any idea ?

Comment: You can switch the result codes. Its based on your usecase. For requestCode, yeah its my mistake. In hurry I forgot to replace correctly.